# Parsing data using QJson on mac

Tags: macos, qt, qjson

I am working on Qt project. I have installed QJson successfully. And have used parser to parse the data.My code get compiled successfully but at run time it is giving me following error:

dyld: Library not loaded: libqjson.0.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/sanjay/untitled1-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_3_in_PATH_*System*_Debug/untitled1.app/Contents/MacOS/untitled1

Reason: image not found

I have added library as external library in Qt creater. It added following code to my .pro file:

macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build/_preferred_path_/lib/ -lqjson

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../build/_preferred_path_/include/qjson

DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../build/_preferred_path_/include/qjson

Could anybody tell me please What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the library is located with your application's app file. Give full path names like LIBS += "lib/libqjson.dylib"

I used the above directive and it worked for me.

Comment: Hi Aakash .thanx for your quick reply. As you said I have copied my lib and include folder into the folder containing my .app file. But still it is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If your application compiles successfully then it means that project configuration defined in pro file is correct (including LIBS configuration).

In this case your application fails on runtime, so that means means that libqjson.0.dylib could not be found in library path. First check how json library is linked with your library using otool tool (http://tech-queries.blogspot.com/2011/04/dynamic-library-dependency-on-mac-os-x.html). This tool will help you to detect the problem, after detection you may:

- copy libqjson.0.dylib in appropriate location
- correct link using install_name_tool tool http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html

relinking of library step may be set as post build step in in pro file. Here is example:

```
macx {
    QMAKE_POST_LINK = install_name_tool -change libqjson.0.dylib @loader_path/relative_path_to_library/libqjson.0.dylib  your_binary_file
```

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal, type this:

```
otool -L /Users/sanjay/untitled1-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_3_in_PATH_System_Debug/untitled1.app/Contents/MacOS/untitled1
```

It will tell you where each of the dependent libraries is expected to be.

Comment: Hi stephen I have tried this already. It is giving me path for all other libraries but not for libqjson.0.dylib.